# F is the constant function

Tags: real-analysis

I am absolutely lost on how to begin this proof:

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha >1$ and all $x,y \in (a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$.

Any starting hints would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried finding a counterexample? can you find a linear function or a function constant except at a point that meets the condition? why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$0 \le|f'(x)|=|\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}|  \le\lim_{y\to x} M|x-y|^{\alpha-1}=0.$$

Comment: you da man paul.

Comment: I assume it's easy to show why these limits (incl the derivative) exist?

Comment: @AAA One should be obvious, the other an obvious consequence of the existence of the first.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative solution, without using derivatives (this uses more of the metric structure of $[a,b]$). Let $c$ be any point of $[a,b]$. Let's show that $f(a)=f(c)$. Given $n\geq 1$, we can decompose the interval $[a,b]$ in $n$ subintervals, with the points $x_i=a+i(c-a)/n$ for $i=0,\ldots,n$. Then
\begin{align*}
|f(a)-f(c)|&=|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})|\\
&\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i+1})|\leq M\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|x_i-x_{i+1}|^\alpha\\
&=M\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{c-a}{n}\right)^\alpha=nM\frac{(c-a)^\alpha}{n^\alpha}=M(c-a)^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}
\end{align*}
Since $\alpha>1$, then $n^{1-\alpha}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so $f(a)=f(c)$ for all $c$, thus $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the function is differentiable, and that the derivative is zero everywhere.